# autoincrement attribute is always null after save()

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have table `query` with field `id` which is **autoincrement primary key**.

**Model**

```
class Query extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%query}}';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'created_at'], 'integer'],
            [['data'], 'string'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
$q = new Query();
$q->created_at = time();
$q->data = Json::encode($query);
if ($q->save())
    echo $q->id == null ? "null" : $q->id;
else
    echo "Validation error";
```

Result is `null`, though new record with incremented id does occur in database.

Also I see only `insert` record in db log, but no record to obtain inserted row id.

What's wrong?

Comment: Does the same happen when you remove `primaryKey()` method?

Comment: why you have redefined  the primaryKey() method ?.. ActiveRecord have already this method

Comment: Well, have removed `primaryKey()`. Calling implicit `primaryKey()` returns **['id']**, `getPrimaryKey()` returns **null**.

Comment: specifying primary key in rules is not needed, try to remove it

Answer (score 0):

as  you can see  in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php

there is already a primaryKey method

```
public static function primaryKey()
{
    return static::getTableSchema()->primaryKey;
}
```

that return the proper primaryKey for the tableSchema

so you should not redefine this method  ..

the method is specifically called  primaryKey() not getPrimaryKey() .. this last one is the magic getter  .. and return a value for var $primaryKey ..

if no insert is performed  could be you have some validation problems .. try (just for debugging) using `save(false)`

Comment: You right, after all I have removed my implementation of primaryKey(). But it doesn't solve the problem I told about.

Comment: when  explain better  the problem 'told about' is not clear to me .. anyway answer updated  witha brief suggestion